# What should I do to get the first example of ttk.style working properly?

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter, ttk

I wanted to try the `ttk.Style()` settings, so I copied the example from the docs at [Ttk Styling](https://docs.python.org/3/library/tkinter.ttk.html#ttk-styling) and ran it. I noticed that no matter what I set the "raised" parameter to, it looks the same. Here's the code I ran:

```
from tkinter import ttk
import tkinter

root = tkinter.Tk()
```

Running Python 3.10.8

```
ttk.Style().configure("TButton", padding=10, relief="raised",
   background="#fff")

btn = ttk.Button(text="Sample")
btn.pack()

root.mainloop()
```

Running this, the button looks like this:

[image]

If I change "raised" to "flat" or "sunken", it looks the same. What should I do to see the button style change?

Answer (score -1):

The button doesn't know you want it to use the style defined above. Try adding `style=[style_name]` to to the `btn` definition. Here is an example below.

```
from tkinter import ttk
import tkinter

root = tkinter.Tk()

style=ttk.Style()
style.configure("TButton", padding=10, relief="raised",
   background="#fff")

btn = ttk.Button(text="Sample", style= "TButton")
btn.pack()

root.mainloop()
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: OK, tried that, no joy.  both raised and sunken still look the same.

Comment: @user1443098 what version of python are you using?

Comment: Python 3.10.8 one one machine and 3.11.0 on another with same results

Comment: Well, I'm not sure what ttk is doing, but regular tkinter seems to work:
    from tkinter import *

    root = Tk()

    B1 = Button(root, text ="FLAT", relief=FLAT ).pack()
    B2 = Button(root, text ="RAISED", relief=RAISED ).pack()
    B3 = Button(root, text ="SUNKEN", relief=SUNKEN ).pack()
    B4 = Button(root, text ="GROOVE", relief=GROOVE ).pack()
    B5 = Button(root, text ="RIDGE", relief=RIDGE ).pack()

    root.mainloop()

Comment: Sure, that's correct vanilla tkinter works.  My mission today is to understand and use ttk styles